# How to fetch data again from an API after something changed in a component using Observables?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular6

I have a `DataServive`, that fetches content from an API:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable()

export class DataService {
  this.request = {
     count: 10
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private handleError(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  public getData(count): Observable<any> {
    this.request.count = count;

    return this.http.post<any>(environment.api + '/path', this.request).pipe(
      map(response => {
        return response;
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        this.handleError(error);
        return [];
      })
    );
  }
}
```

This `DataServie` is consumned by a component like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  const subscriber = this.dataService.getData(this.count).subscribe((data) => { this.data = data; });
}
```

And it works fine.

---

However the user is able to change the variable `this.count` (how many items should be displayed) in the component. So I want to get new data from the server as soon as this value changes.

*How can I achieve this?*

Of course I could call `destroy` on `this.subscriber` and  call `ngOnInit()` again, but that dosn't seem like the right way.

Comment: is count bound to an input control?

Comment: @vikas Yes, the user selects a value from a dropdown and then a method `selectCount(value)` is called in the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest ways is just to unsubscribe:

```
subscriber: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  this.makeSubscription(this.count);
}

makeSubscription(count) {
  this.subscriber = this.dataService.getData(this.count).subscribe((data) => { this.data = data; });
}

functionInvokedWhenCountChanges(newCount) {
  this.subscriber.unsubscribe();
  makeSubscription(newCount);
}
```

But because `count` argument is just a one number it means HTTP always asks for data from 0 to x. In this case, you can better create another subject where you can store previous results (so you don't need to make useless HTTP requests) and use that subject as your data source. That needs some planning on your streams, but is definitely the preferred way.

Comment: OP, accept this answer. Made a good point on storing previous results to reduce HTTP requests.

Comment: Ah, so it's ok to just unsubscribe and resubscribe. Is there an Angular way to cache results or do I have to manually keep track of previous requests with different parameters? Thanks a lot for our help.

Comment: @lampshade There are some good tutorials about this, like - https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2018/03/05/advanced-caching-with-rxjs.html  . To make it simple - you can store response data in a **Subject**, when you again ask for data, you check if `count` is `<=` the value from Subject, if not, you cal HTTP for the missing data (need another endpoint or configure the current to accept **from** parameter).

Comment: Ah I see, that's what `Subject` is for. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you could also in the same manner push new values from HTTP call to that subject and insted subscribe to it (exported as Observable (recommended)), so you wont ned to unsubscribe every time

Answer (score 0):

When the user changes `count`, call `getData(count)` again with the updated `count` value. Need to see your `html` file, but having a button with `(click)="getData(count)"` may help.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work, withou unsibscribing first. The `getData()` method is called, but `this.data` in the component isn't updated. Or maybe I'm overlooking something.